# Reverse ^ operator for decryption

Tags: c, algorithm, security, math, encryption

I'm trying to reverse the following code in order to provide a function which takes the buffer and decrypts it.

```
void crypt_buffer(unsigned char *buffer, size_t size, char *key) {
    size_t i;
    int j;

    j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(j >= KEY_SIZE)
            j = 0;
        buffer[i] ^= key[j];
        j++;
    }
}
```

I was wordering if a simple `buffer[i] ^= (1/key[j]);` will be enough to decrypt the encrypted file. But there will be some issues with truncation, isn't it?

Comment: You should fix your indentation.

Comment: Not a very secure encryption algorithm, see  [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a power operator. It is the XOR operator. The thing that you notice for the XOR operator is that `x ^ k ^ k == x`. That means that your encryption function is already the decryption function when called with the same key and the ciphertext instead of the plaintext.

Comment: Thank you, i should have watched first the operator tables, been a while coding in C

Comment: Also, FYI... this cipher algorithm is known as a "one time pad".  Wikipedia has a decent article on it.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: you'd only be able to say you'd used a "one time pad" if the `key` data was at least as long as the `buffer`, otherwise the `j >= KEY_SIZE` test kicks in and it starts using the "pad" a second time, and further: the same `key` data isn't used again to encrypt other data.

Comment: Good catch.  Missed that part.  Actually, I guess the `j >= KEY_SIZE` makes this algorithm effectively useless for anything other than a toy--or program meant to demonstrate why you should never reuse a key.  Although degree of vulnerability / effort to brute-force crack is proportional to the KEY_SIZE:size ratio.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the `^` is not the “power” operator (there is no such operator) but the “xor” operator.

Which is great news for you (I assume), as the reverse operation of “xor” is “xor” itself :-)